# Using input$ on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to add the output from a drop down list into a field in ggplot

The data fields I want to use has these fields:
[Data image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAlY5.jpg)
[image]

The code I use to output this in a chart is:

```
ggplot(survey_data_sub, aes(fill=`Education level`, y=`Education level`, 
x=`Developer group`)) +
geom_bar( stat="identity")
```

This works great for showing the Education level results.

I want to make the "fill" and "y" dynamic, from a drop down list.  So I used the below shiny code:

```
sidebarLayout(
           sidebarPanel(
             selectInput("newplot_select", "Choose Breakdown for chart:", 
                         list("UK location", "Education level", "Current 
salary", "Generation"))
               ),

               mainPanel(
                 textOutput("newPlot_selected_filter"),
                 plotOutput("newPlot")
               )
             )


 output$newPlot <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(survey_data_sub, aes(fill=input$newplot_select, 
    y=input$newplot_select, x=`Developer group`)) + 
    geom_bar( stat="identity")

 })
```

the **input$newplot_select** doesent pull in the content from the dropdown list.  If I just output the **input$newplot_select** in a text output it does print the input value.  How can I do that in the ggplot code I have used?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I recommend you to provide a snippet of your data. This is important for people who need to experiment a bit to come to a solution. See how to make a [mcve]. For example, use `dput` to output a subset of your data as text and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: I believe that the problem is that `ggplot` is looking for an object name, but you are passing a string to it.

Comment: Try using `aes_string()` instead of `aes()`. Remember to change the `x` value (`Developer group`) to a string.

Comment: yes sure, im not sure how to add images on here.  Here is a link to the image on my one drive: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiamaSfEoxGOslmo2FhCNbvlsLEK

Comment: @Paranoidantroid: do not use `$` inside `ggplot` call. Here's why https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2693

Comment: This might help if you want to use string inside `aes`:  stackoverflow.com/a/50726130/786542 & stackoverflow.com/a/49870618/786542